# Hadoop2.7 cannot work,the ResourceManager can not start

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop2

The error message is

```
    2015-11-27 13:10:23,653 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Error starting ResourceManager
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.toLowerCase(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
            at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacitySchedulerConfiguration.getAclKey(CapacitySchedulerConfiguration.java:500)
            at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacitySchedulerConfiguration.getAcl(CapacitySchedulerConfiguration.java:508)
            at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacitySchedulerConfiguration.getAcls(CapacitySchedulerConfiguration.java:521)
            at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.AbstractCSQueue.setupQueueConfigs(AbstractCSQueue.java:262)
            at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.ParentQueue.setupQueueConfigs(ParentQueue.java:107)
            at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.ParentQueue.<init>(ParentQueue.java:98)
            at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler.parseQueue(CapacityScheduler.java:610)
            at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler.initializeQueues(CapacityScheduler.java:473)
            at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler.
    initScheduler(CapacityScheduler.java:303)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler.serviceInit(CapacityScheduler.java:333)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:107)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager$RMActiveServices.serviceInit(ResourceManager.java:556)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.createAndInitActiveServices(ResourceManager.java:984)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.serviceInit(ResourceManager.java:251)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager.main(ResourceManager.java:1207)
2015-11-27 13:10:23,673 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Transitioning to standby state
2015-11-27 13:10:23,673 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Transitioned to standby state
2015-11-27 13:10:23,673 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down ResourceManager at ubuntu1/192.168.1.36
************************************************************/
```

How can I solve this problem.

Comment: my java version is jdk1.7

Comment: Can you check if your %HADOOP_HOME%/share/hadoop/common directory contains: hadoop-common jar? And if this jar is present, it should contain "StringUtils" class. Also, I want to know what is the version of your hadoop-common jar? Mine is hadoop-common-2.7.1.

Comment: yes, the %HADOOP_HOME%/share/hadoop/common directory contains hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar,and the version is 2.7.1

Comment: The error is occurring, because it is not able to find "toLowerCase()" method in StringUtils.java, which is part of hadoop-common-2.71.jar.  This is occurring while instantiating the CapacityScheduler.

Comment: The hadoop2.7.1 downloaded from the official website of Apache so, that I should now how to fix it.I am feel very troubled:(

Comment: If you installed from official page, then it should work without any problems. If you downloaded the entire package containing all the jar files, then there should not be any issues.